# JSON in Wordpress DB: two keys/values for a value/key

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, wordpress, data-structures

I'm trying to understand what kind of `json` this structure can be:

`{s:11:"current_tab";s:7:"content";}`

At least I believe that it is `json`, can anybody can help me understanding how I can query and work with this?
I found it in a `mysql` DB with wordpress, in the `wp_postmeta` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These *arrays* are called ***serialized data representation***. That type is used for storing or passing PHP values without losing their type or structure, you can normally find this type of data stored in plugins or themes configuration, but it's widely used when working with WordPress databases.

Let’s say a theme is creating an array for storing color and a path.

In pure PHP, it looks like:

```
$settings = array(
'color' => 'green',
'path' => 'https://example.com'
);
```

When that array is stored in the database, it is converted into the serialized representation and looks like:

```
a:2:{s:5:"color";s:5:"green";s:4:"path";s:18:"https://example.com";}
```

The advantage is that the serialized data representation can be stored in the database much more effectively than the PHP array. The drawback is that the serialized data can not be changed by a simple search & replace as you would do with a text editor.

You can find more info about this type of data (and also for the PHP methods used to create and retrieve them) by searching for *serialized data in WordPress*. Also you can find a detailed example [here](https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/)

Comment: ouch, that's why I can't see it, I'm not very familiar with PHP.

Thanks!